# how to show a textview on top of viewpager actionbar and under the supportactionbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to show a TextView between the main actionbar and viewpager action bar but it is showing under the viewpager action bar. here is my code

promotions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/promotionheader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewHeading"
            android:text="@string/heading_promotion"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border_promotion"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/promotionheader"
        tools:context=".Promotions"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnStores"
            style="?android:attr/imageButtonStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:onClick="startSelectStore"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_home" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCoupons"
            style="?android:attr/imageButtonStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:onClick="startCouponActivity"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_coupon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnNotifications"
            style="?android:attr/imageButtonStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:onClick="startNotificationActivity"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_notification" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
            style="?android:attr/imageButtonStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:onClick="startAboutActivity"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_about" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Promotions.java

```
public class Promotions extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    ArrayList<String> shopList;

    // TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.promotions);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View customActionBar = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_promotion, null);

        //-- Set Custom icon in ActionBar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customActionBar);

        ImageButton ibItem1 = (ImageButton) customActionBar.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnSettings);
        ibItem1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Promotions.this, SelectStore.class));
            }
        });

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        //View customActionBar1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_promotion_tab, null);
        //actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBar1);
        actionBar.invalidateOptionsMenu();

        //-- Get value from intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        shopList = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("selectedStoreList");

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(shopList.get(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }

    }

    public void startSelectStore(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Promotions.this, SelectStore.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void startCouponActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Promotions.this, Coupons.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void startNotificationActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Promotions.this, Notifications.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void startAboutActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Promotions.this, AboutStore.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new PromotionFragment();
                    args.putInt("fragNum", 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new PromotionFragment();
                    args.putInt("fragNum", 2);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new PromotionFragment();
                    args.putInt("fragNum", 3);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new PromotionFragment();
                    args.putInt("fragNum", 4);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment = new PromotionFragment();
                    args.putInt("fragNum", 5);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    fragment = new PromotionFragment();
                    args.putInt("fragNum", 6);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    fragment = new PromotionFragment();
                    args.putInt("fragNum", 7);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    fragment = new PromotionFragment();
                    args.putInt("fragNum", 8);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    fragment = new PromotionFragment();
                    args.putInt("fragNum", 9);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    fragment = new PromotionFragment();
                    args.putInt("fragNum", 10);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (shopList.isEmpty()) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return shopList.size();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My UI looks like
I want Promotions & Events to be on top of ALL Stores

[image: this]

Someone pls help...

Comment: by creating custom header instead of actionbar or toolbar you can achieve what you want. otherwise i am not sure whether it is achievable

Comment: why you have taken the single textview in linear layout separately whereas your parent is relative layout.. Moreover you didnot include toolbar in it

Comment: try 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" for viewpager

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :---

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Dashboard">

        <!-- our toolbar -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:alpha="3"
            android:background="#5d4292"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/menu_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:alpha="3"
            android:background="#5d4292"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <!-- View pager to swipe views -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```